# How to compile a Java source code (using javac 11.0.13) that uses JavaFx on a Linux machine?

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-errors

The line `import javafx.application.Application;` gives me the following compile-time error:
`error: package javafx.application does not exist`

I'm using Linux Lite 5.6 (Ubuntu 20.04) and `java --version` gives me:

```
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you installed javafx? If yes, are you including it in your classpath when building?

Comment: I thought javafx comes together with the java API so i didn't include anything.

I tried searching for javafx on my system and I found a few folders, but I have no idea which one is the right one, if there is a right one:

`/home/kamui/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/213.5744.223/plugins/javaFX`

`/home/kamui/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/`  

I searched on the web and tried something like `javac --module-path <the path to openjfx` Main.java, but I got the same error.

Comment: Read and follow the documentation at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), or, because you are using Idea, create a [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

Comment: Check your distribution's library manager or  see [_Getting Started with JavaFX_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), which cites JavaFX runtime downloads.

Comment: Thank you, both! I managed to start compile and run from the command line.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: @trashgod, do you mean that I should write the solution in an answer? I succeeded using the links you guys provided

Comment: Yes; try to include as much detail as you can—intended use, development environment, other libraries, etc.; pretend you're explaining it to a less experienced friend or colleague.

Comment: As others said, your app needs access to the *OpenJFX* libraries at compile-time and at runtime. One way to provide them is to bundle a copy with your app. Another is to compile on, and deploy to, a machine that has a JDK already installed that includes the libraries. At least two vendors provide an edition of their JDK product to include OpenJFX: *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems, and *LibericaFX* by BellSoft.

Answer (score 1):

I thought JavaFX came together with Java SDK but that doesn't seem to be the case since JDK 11.
In order to compile and run JavaFX apps, the JavaFX SDK (which no longer comes together with the Java SDK) is required.

---

These are the steps required to follow in order to be able to compile and run JavaFX apps:

Step 1. Checking if you already have Java installed

> You can check if you have Java installed by running `java --version`
> in the terminal. The output should be something like this:
>
> ```
> openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-39)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-39, mixed mode, sharing)
> ```
>
> If you get an output similar to this (note that you can have a
> different version installed), then proceed to **Step 3.**
> If you get
> an error that probably means you don't have Java installed and you
> need to install it. (**go the next step**)

Step 2. Installing/Downloading Java

> You can find the Java SDK for downloading [here](https://jdk.java.net/).
> Click on **JDK 17**.
> From **Builds** choose and download the appropriate version for you system.
> Save it somewhere on your system. I will use `~/Programs`.
>
> > It is recommended that you also check the sum of the file.
> >
> > For that download the **sha256** file next to the Java version you chose and save it where you saved the Java archive.
> >
> > Open a terminal or use an existing one and **cd** to the place where you downloaded the Java archive and the .sha256 file.
> >
> > At the moment I'm writing this the **sha256** for Linux/x64 doesn't contain the filename.
> >
> > You can either edit the **.sha256** file and add on the first line, right after the checksum, 2 spaces followed by the name of the Java archive you downloaded
> > you can run
> > `echo "  <name/of/java/archive>" | tee --append <name/of/.sha256/file>`
> > to achieve that
> >
> > it should like like this `1c0a73cbb863aad579b967316bf17673b8f98a9bb938602a140ba2e5c38f880a  openjdk-17.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`,
> >
> > then run
> > `sha256sum -c <name/of/java/archive>`
> > (in my case, the name is *openjdk-17.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz*)
> >
> > or, if you don't want to edit the file, then you can run
> > `test $(sha256sum <name/of/java/archive> | awk '{print $1}') = $(cat <name/of/.sha256/file>) && echo OK`
> >
> > The output in the first method should be `<name/of/java/archive>: OK` and in the second it should be `OK`
>
> Extract the archive with the command `tar -xvzf <name/of/java/archive>`
>
> Go to the directory that was created by extracting the file, in my case it's *jdk-17.0.1*
> and run `./bin/java --version` to check if java was downloaded correctly and that it works.
>
> Now you can make the java and javac commands available from anywhere or you can go to **Step 3.**.
>
> > Method 1: aliases
> >
> > add
> >
> > ```
> > alias javac="<path/to/jdk>/bin/javac" 
> > alias java="<path/to/jdk>/bin/java"
> > ```
> >
> > to `~/.bashrc` (or the equivalent, depending on your distro/shell)
> >
> > Method 2:  adding the bin folder to the PATH environment variable
> >
> > add
> > `export PATH=$PATH:<path/to/jdk>/bin`
> > to `~/.bashrc` (or the equivalent, depending on your distro/shell)

Step 3. installing/downloading JavaFX

> Go [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), head to **Downloads** section, choose the SDK that fits your system and download it. Eventually check the sha256 sum.
>
> Extract the archive using `unzip <archive/name>`
>
> For simplicity you can add aliases for compiling and running JavaFX applications. I'm using the following:
>
> ```
> alias java='/home/kamui/Programs/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java' 
> alias javac='/home/kamui/Programs/jdk-17.0.1/bin/javac'
> alias javafx='java --module-path /home/kamui/Programs/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml'
> alias javafxc='javac --module-path /home/kamui/Programs/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml'
> ```
>
> Note that you don't need to add `javafx.fxml` if you don't use it

Step 4. compile & run

> Single source code file
>
> > For a single source code file, like HelloFX.java you can run the following commands:
> >
> > ```
> > # make sure you are in the directory where HelloFX.java is located 
> > javafxc HelloFX.java # to compile it 
> > javafx HelloFX # to run it
> > ```
> >
> > The source for these steps, where you can also find the HelloFX.java file is https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx
>
> Multiple source code files
>
> > For more complex directory structures, like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCz3l.png) (it's just what IntelliJ provides when you create a new JavaFX Project) you can
> > do the following:
> >
> > Make sure you are in the folder where `src` is located.
> >
> > Compile with:
> > `javafxc -d ./out -sourcepath src/ src/main/java/com/example/a7/HelloApplication.java`
> >
> > Run with:
> > `javafx -classpath ./out com.example.a7.HelloApplication`
> > Notes:
> >
> > 1. I have no idea what `module-info.java` is or does.
> > 2. When I used the CLI to compile the code generated by IntelliJ for a JavaFX project, it failed at runtime (more specifically, at loading the FXML) because it seems that it can only find it inside the `out` folder (I tested it using *getClass().getResource()* and *getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()*)
> >    In order to fix this you can
> >    move/copy the .fxml file somewhere in the `out` folder and set the proper path for the FXMLLoader inside the code.